# Add a large amount of files in a .vdproj (Visual Studio Installer) file

Tags: vdproj

my problem is : 
I have a VB .NET project, with an installation project made with the old poor "Visual Studio Installer".
The version of Visual Studio I'm currently using is 2015.
Now I need to insert into the installer project a huge amount of file, from different directories,
and the IDE doesn't let me to add multiple files in subdirectories, with a simple "copy and paste into".
Apparently, I have to manually create, into the file system, every sigle directory that I want to have in the final installation.
I've already did a little program that inserts those files programmatically into the main project file (.vbproj), that's simply an xml file, but the .vdproj file seems more "tricky" do manage,
it contains GUID numbers, as 9F6F8455-1EF1-4B85-886A-4223BCC8E7F7 that I'm not sure I'd want to tangle with.
Anyone has ever dealt with a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself.
Simply I was wrong, you can actually copy the directories you want to add, from a file explorer windows, and then paste it into the File System Windows of the installation project.
Anyway, I think I'm leaving here this question, in case anyone else would need that.